# "crontab -l" list all the cron jobs but not give any response to run-parts

Tags: cron

I have added WordPress cronjobs to crontab via `crontab -e`.  But when I try  `run-parts /etc/cron.hourly -v` , it's not executing my 5 minutes crontab. How do I verify my crontab jobs running properly?

When I run `crontab -l`, it shows my jobs like below.

```
MAILTO=myemail@gmail.com
15 3 * * 7 certbot renew --post-hook "service nginx restart"
7 0 * * * "/root/.acme.sh"/acme.sh --cron --home "/root/.acme.sh" > /dev/null
*/5 * * * * curl https://site1.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * curl https://www.site2.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * curl https://www.site3.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * curl https://www.site4.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * curl https://site5.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: AFAIK user crontabs (managed via `crontab -e`) are separate from the systemwide crontabs in `/etc/cron.hourly` etc. Why do you expect `run-parts` to show your jobs?

Comment: I need to verify my cronjobs run properly.